# error in installing xampp in windows environment

Tags: xampp

i used to get this error when running xampp . I had already installed MYSQL in my laptop

```
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:08:05 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

how can i overcome this thing?????

Comment: Did you press the Logs button to view error logs? How about the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Have you checked if there is another instance of MySQL running? Is your firewall blocking the MySQL port? (default is 3306) Like mustaccio said, did you press Logs button to get more info? If so, you can post more info in your question.